# i want new line after one list in 2D Array in python with a file text

Tags: python, arrays, file, text, 2d

**this is my code**

```
list = [["UUU","UCU", "UAU", "UGU"],["UUC", " UCC ", "UAC", " UGC"]]
    
    file = open("codons.txt","w") 
    
    for i in list:
        
        for j in i:
         file.write(j)
         file.write(" ")
```

**this is the desired output**

```
UUU UCU UAU UGU

UUC UCC UAC UGC
```

Comment: Please format the code using the correct formatting - see the FAQ https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Also what is goiung wrong and how have you tried to debug it.

Comment: codons is just the name of my file that i save it in

Comment: Also don't overwrite builtins such as `list`

Comment: the second value in row 2 has ` UCC ` (space before and after). Do you want to remove the spaces before and after? And for row 2 item 4, there is a space before. The expected output does not have any spaces

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.

Comment: about the space i modify it when i execute the new code thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

The below code will concatenate all the values in each row, then add `\n` to it and write to file.

```
my_list=[["UUU","UCU", "UAU", "UGU"],["UUC", " UCC ", "UAC", " UGC"]]

with open("codons.txt", "w") as f_out:
    for line in my_list:
        f_out.write(' '.join(line) + '\n')
```

Output of this will be:

```
UUU UCU UAU UGU
UUC  UCC  UAC  UGC
```

Note here that I am not removing the leading and trailing spaces. If you want the leading and trailing spaces to be removed, the join() statement needs to be modified.

If you want the leading and trailing spaces to be stripped so the output looks like this:

```
UUU UCU UAU UGU
UUC UCC UAC UGC
```

Then use the below code instead:

```
my_list=[["UUU","UCU", "UAU", "UGU"],["UUC", " UCC ", "UAC", " UGC"]]

with open("codons.txt", "w") as f_out:
    for line in my_list:
        f_out.write(' '.join([item.strip() for item in line]) + '\n')
```

Comment: Of course I don't mind, I voted @joeFerndz.